# printf против сout C++

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::cout << aaa << " " << bbb << std::endl;` 
(переменные `ааа`, `bbb`) 
Можно ли как нибудь заменить эту запись на printf?

Comment: Можно. Укажите тип переменных `aaa` и `bbb`.

Comment: можете показать как будет это заполнено через printf на примере?

Comment: просто я категорически не хочу через тип переменных указывать cout std , хочу научится через printf

Comment: @xCEN Через printf() надо тип указывать в спецификаторах. Например, если тип aaa - int, а тип bbb - строка символов (char*), то это так будет выглядеть: printf("%d %s\n", aaa,bbb);

Comment: что означает %d , %s ?

Comment: просто я пока новичок учу с++

Comment: %d - int, %s - строка. Подробнее читайте спецификацию на printf(): https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Спецификаторы преобразования. Если новичок, то я бы вам посоветовал всё-таки остановиться на `std::cout`. Подробнее про [спецификаторы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) + примеры. Там не всё так просто и довольно легко ошибиться.

Comment: Вместо %d и %s printf() подставляет значения соответствующих параметров.

Comment: через обратную связь к вам можно обращаться например дискорд?

Comment: помогли спасибо

Comment: Это вопрос типа: "Не охота книжки читать, могу ли я с вашей помощью освоить язык программирования?"  Это азы, которые есть во всех учебниках, и нужно читать, а если что то конкретное не понятно или не получается, тогда обращаться с вопросом в SО.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что  решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям

Answer (score 3):

Функция `printf()` предполагает указание формата выводимых данных. Для разных типов данных это обозначение (спецификатор) будет разным, например, `%s` для строки, `%d` для целого числа и т.д.
Например, если Ваши переменные `aaa` и `bbb` стокового типа и `aaa = "яблоко"`, а `bbb = "груша"`, то вывести их на экран с помощью `printf()` можно, например, так:

`printf("%s %s",aaa,bbb);` 
Вывод: `яблоко груша`

Образно говоря, вместо спецификаторов (%s, %d, %f и др.) в строку подставляются переменные соответствующих типов, которые Вы указываете после кавычек через запятую.
То есть, если написать:
`printf("Текст перед строкой 1, а вот и строка 1: %s, и строка 2: %s",aaa,bbb);` 
То вывод будет такой:
`Текст перед строкой 1, а вот и строка 1: яблоко, и строка 2: груша`

Больше информации в [статье](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/printf).